# Angular 2 Dynamic child-parent radiobutton

Tags: form, angular2, typescript, radio, dynamic

Здравствуйте, уважаемые. Я пытаюсь построить динамические формы в Ангулар2. Но что то у меня не получается, прошу помочь найти ошибку в коде.

Идея в следующем, есть app component (parent), child component(child), в child содержится верстка для элементов типа инпут (радио, чекбокс, текст).

Пытаюсь используя reactiveforms модуль построить динамическую форму https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Чекбокс и текст поля работают верно, а вот с радио какая то непонятная вещь происходит, помогите найти ошибку пожалуйста.
Пример кода построения радио инпутов

```
<div *ngFor="let item of fields"> 
  <label class="center-block">
    <input [type]="item.type" [formControlName]="item.name" name="hero" value="{{item.value}}">
    {{item.value}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Шаблон родителя

```
  <div [formGroup]="myform">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <child [fields]="fields" [myform]="myform"></child>
    </div>
```

Код родителя app.component.ts

```
 myform: FormGroup;
  fields=[
    {
      type: "radio",
      value: "flight",
      name: "hero"
    },
    {
      type: "radio",
      value: "vision",
      name: "hero"
    },
    {
      type: "radio",
      value: "strenth",
      name: "hero"
    }
  ];
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myform = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ],
      hero: 'flight',
      sidekick: ''
    });
  }
```

Код потомка child

```
 @Input() fields;
 @Input() myform: FormGroup;
 constructor() {}
```

Поля name и sidekick работают правильно, никак не пойму в чем ошибка с радио кнопками.
Ссылка на планк http://plnkr.co/edit/AtoKY2hWQkfS9oVXmmYP?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй строку
`<input [type]="item.type" [formControlName]="item.name" name="hero" value="{{item.value}}">`
 на
              `<input type="radio" formControlName="hero" value="{{item?.value}}">`

Comment: Работает. Достаточно было поменять [type]="item.type" на type="radio" видимо angular делает привязку до вычисления этого свойства, если расскажите почему работает именно так, то буду благодарен.

Comment: скорее всего это осбенности ReactiveFroms, при помощи класса FromArray мы можем создавать динамически элементы формы и они привязываются, но ты здесь пытаешься создавать просто динамический html, да и если посудить логически, зачем так делать? У тебя же не может быть в форме сначала 3 radio, потом checkbox, а после опять радио с этим же name?

Comment: Да, с одинаковым name конечно будут только однотипные инпуты, просто я хотел сделать универсальный код для построения radio и checkbox инпутов, но что то не прокатило. Хотя тут https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property сказано, что устанавливается только свойства и вроде когда меняешь type у инпута он соответственно меняется, в общем видимо баг ангуляра, так как видимо не вызывается https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor и не срабатывает установка ацесора

Answer (score 0):

А на мой взгляд, это происходит из за того, что одинаковы ключ и значение `{type: "radio"}` с атрибутом `[type]="{{item.type}}"` и `ReactiveFroms` думает, что создаётся обычный элемент.